# How to find the list of SQL instances running on machine by using the registry?

Tags: c#, sql, registry

The goal of the code is to obtain the SQL instances on the machine using the registry and then use it in other methods such as a button click.

Here is the method that gets the string. It runs with no errors:

```
private string LocateSQLInstance()
{
    bool flag = false;
    string keyPath = "";

    try
    {
        keyPath = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Instance Names\\SQL";
        flag = this.CheckRegKeyPath(keyPath);
    }
    finally
    {
        MyProject.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.Close();
    }

    string str;

    if (flag)
    {
        try
        {
            str = RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(MyProject.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\" + keyPath,"", "")).ToString();
            return str;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(ex);
            this.WriteNote(">>Cannot Get Instance Names. Error while attempting to read registry! " + ex.ToString(), false);
            str = "ERR";
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
        }
    }
    else
        str = "NOSQL";

    return str;
}
```

Here is the button click method. I would like it to show the instances that it found but it seems to be coming up blank:

```
private void VerifyUMButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str2 = LocateSQLInstance();
    this.WriteNote(str2);
}
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is [reduce your code to the specific method or request that is not doing what you think](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can do that by [using the debugger](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: the code supplied is the code not doing what I think it should. This is not the code for the entire program. Also, the debugger in visual studio does not help in this case because it is compiling with no errors. In the program, when i use the VerifyUMButton button, it writes a blank line, not the sql instance names as I expect. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear in the original post.

Comment: Are you sure that the value you want is in the `(Default)` value under the `Instance Names` key?  Mine is empty.  The code you supplied will return the value of `(Default)` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names` Are you trying to enumerate the values in there?